# Google Apps Script XMLHttpRequest not showing parameters

Tags: google-apps-script, xmlhttprequest

I am able to make the POST request to my google apps script web app, but I can't access my e.parameters when I log them.

HTML CODE:

```
<form onsubmit="submitForm(event)">
  <input type="text" name="fname" required>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS CODE:

```
function submitForm(e){
  e.preventDefault()

   var url = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/exec"
   var params = "employeeStatus='Active'&name='Henry'";
 
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

   xhr.open("POST",url,true)
  
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  
   xhr.onreadystatechange = ()=>{
     var readyState = xhr.readyState 
     var status = xhr.status

     if(readyState == 4 && status == 200){
      var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
      console.log(response)
     }
   }

  xhr.send(params)
}
```

APPS SCRIPT CODE:

```
function doPost(e){
  var values = e.parameters;
  Logger.log(values)
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"a":5,"b":2}))
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I've iterated the apps script code to try and log the `e.parameters` but I'm unable to get anything to work.

***NOTES:

1. I'm aware that the "params" value is NOT the same as the form input value
2. I return the JSON string just to ensure that the code is running all the way through and I can practice JSON.parse/JSON.stringify on the client-side.

Answer (score 1):

When I saw your script, I think that your value of `e.parameters` is `{"employeeStatus":["'Active'"],"name":["'Henry'"]}`.

About `I've iterated the apps script code to try and log the e.parameters but I'm unable to get anything to work.`, I think that the reason for your issue is due to that your request of "XMLHttpRequest"  include no access token. From your request, I thought that the settings of Web Apps might be `Execute as: Me` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone` with V8 runtime. If my understanding is correct, the reason for your issue is due to that.

If you want to show `Logger.log(values)` in the log, please include the access token to the request header as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function submitForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"; // Your web apps URL.
  url += "?access_token=###your access token###";

  var params = "employeeStatus=Active&name=Henry";
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    var readyState = xhr.readyState;
    var status = xhr.status;
    if (readyState == 4 && status == 200) {
      var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      console.log(response);
    }
  }
  xhr.send(params);
}
```

- In this case, as a test, you can simply retrieve your access token by the following Google Apps Script. `// DriveApp.getFiles()` is put for automatically detecting the scope of Drive API for accessing Web Apps. The expiration time of this access token is 1 hour. Please be careful about this. When the expiry time is over, please retrieve the access token again.

  ```
    const sample = _ => {
      console.log(ScriptApp.getOAuthToken());
      // DriveApp.getFiles()
    }
  ```
- When the above script is run, the following value is shown in the log by `Logger.log(values)`.

  - `{access_token=[###], employeeStatus=[Active], name=[Henry]}` : This is due to `Logger.log`.
  - When `console.log(values)` is used, `{ access_token: [ '###' ], employeeStatus: [ 'Active' ], name: [ 'Henry' ]}` is shown.

#### Note:

- As another approach, for example, when you want to check the value of `e` of `doPost`, I think that you can store the value in a Spreadsheet as a log as follows. By this, when `doPost` is run, the value of `e` is stored in the Spreadsheet as a log. In this case, the access token is not required to be used.

  ```
    function doPost(e) {
      SpreadsheetApp.openById("###spreadsheetId###").getSheets()[0].appendRow([new Date(), JSON.stringify(e)]);
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ "a": 5, "b": 2 }))
    }
  ```

#### Note

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### Reference:

- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Hi @Tanaike. Thanks for your help. So here is another issue I'm finding. As you can see from the code I provided the <form> had no action or method attributes. When I added those to the form, I was able to submit the form and log the values, however it is redirecting me (default behavior). That's why I tried using an XHR. Maybe you can try it and tell me what you think. I'll give it a shot with the access token as you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: @Andres Alvarez Thank you for replying. About `here is another issue I'm finding.`, I would like to support you. But, that is different from your question. So, first, I would like to resolve your this question. After your this question was resolved, I would like to think of `here is another issue I'm finding.` as a new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike. So I implemented the solution you suggested about using the authorization token and using a spreadhseet. However when I post the values into the cells I get a weird JSON string that I am unable to access. Looks something like this: `{parameters={fname=[Ljava.lang.Object;@7d4f11b8}`. As I mentioned in my previous comment, if I simply submit the form with the action/method attributes in the form tag, I can access the parameters with no problem but the page redirects after submission.

Comment: @Andres Alvarez Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `Looks something like this: {parameters={fname=[Ljava.lang.Object;@7d4f11b8}.`, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. When I tested my proposed script, the correct value is added to the sheet. But, I would like to support you. So, in order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide the whole script reflecting my proposed script? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Andres Alvarez I deeply apologize that when I tested my proposed script, no issue occurs and the correct values are put to the sheet. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: no need to apologize, I somehow managed to work around the issue simply using jQuery. For some reason that works a lot better than using an XMLHttpRequest object